# Calculate date and weekending date on Presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Given day, month and year as integer columns in the table, calculate the date and weekending date from these values.

I tried following

```
select date_parse(cast (2020 as varchar)||cast (03 as varchar)||cast (02 as varchar),'%Y%m%d')
```

returns an error saying "INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "202032" is too short"

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide some sample inputs and their corresponding outputs that you would like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`format()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) + `cast` to `date`:

```
presto> SELECT CAST(format('%d-%d-%d', 2020, 3, 31) AS date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-03-31
```

Since Athena is still based on Presto .172, it doesn't have this function yet, so you can do the same without `format`:

```
presto> SELECT CAST(CAST(2020 AS varchar) || '-' || CAST(3 AS varchar) || '-' || CAST(31 AS varchar) AS date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-03-31
```