# How to combine day, month, year fields into a date in Presto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Entries in my table are saved with a date, as distinct fields `day`, `month` and `year`. I want to read the dates as Date type.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```sql
date(format('%d-%d-%d', 2020, 3, 31))
```

Based on [Calculate date and weekending date on Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942502/calculate-date-and-weekending-date-on-presto)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

```sql
SELECT date(date_parse('2020' || '04' || '08', '%Y%m%d'))

SELECT date(date_parse(CAST(year as VARCHAR) || '-'  || CAST(month as VARCHAR) || '-'  || CAST(day as VARCHAR), '%Y-%c-%e'))
```

You may need to edit the format based on your data.
https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions

Comment: Here's the tricky part: day, month and year are given as integers, not strings. Hence, the concat operator doesn't apply.

Comment: You can covert it by CAST(col_name as VARCHAR).

Comment: So `date(date_parse(CAST(year as VARCHAR) || CAST(month as VARCHAR) || CAST(day as VARCHAR), '%Y%m%d'))`? -- looks like I'm doing something wrong if it's so complicated.

Comment: We need to pad 0 for month and day. Or you can select date(date_parse(CAST(year as VARCHAR) || '-'  || CAST(month as VARCHAR) || '-'  || CAST(day as VARCHAR), '%Y-%c-%e')).

Comment: Another way: 

```sql
SELECT date(format('%d-%d-%d', 2020, 3, 31))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942502/calculate-date-and-weekending-date-on-presto