# Updating int partitions to yyyy/mm/dd/hh in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

I currently have a datalake setup in s3 with integers in a table setup. Right now I am having trouble querying days of data between months at this point and have been having to pass in individual year, month, and day in the where statement.

```
where
  (year = 2022 and month = 8 and day = 31) or 
  (year = 2022 and month = 9 and day = 1)
```

I want to be able to pass in `between date('yyyy/mm/dd') and date('yyyy/mm/dd')` instead to make my queries work better.

I have setup another database where I am trying to build a better way of doing this by using projections and dates. I have built this table with some input from the Kinesis docs. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `vehicles`(
  `objectid` bigint, 
  `trip_id` string, 
  `vehicle_id` string, 
  `route_id` string, 
  `direction_id` bigint, 
  `timestamp` bigint, 
  `delay` bigint, 
  `delay_type` string, 
  `headsign` string, 
  `route_short_name` string, 
  `route_long_name` string, 
  `longitude` double, 
  `latitude` double)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `agency` string,
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int,
  `hour` int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://transitnode/vehicles/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='transit_node_testing5', 
  'areColumnsQuoted'='false', 
  'averageRecordSize'='115', 
  'classification'='csv', 
  'columnsOrdered'='true', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'delimiter'=',', 
  'exclusions'='[\"s3://transitnode/athena/*\"]', 
  'objectCount'='1640', 
  'recordCount'='144257', 
  'sizeKey'='17310018', 
  
    'projection.enabled' = 'true',

    'projection.agency.type' = 'injected',
    'projection.hour.type' = 'int',
    'projection.hour.interval' = '1',
    'projection.hour.unit' = 'HOURS',

    'projection.day.type' = 'int',
    'projection.day.interval' = '1',
    'projection.day.unit' = 'DAYS',
    
    'projection.month.type' = 'int',
    'projection.month.interval' = '1',
    'projection.month.unit' = 'MONTHS',
        
    'projection.year.type' = 'int',
    'projection.year.interval' = '1',
    'projection.year.unit' = 'YEARS',

    'storage.location.template' = 's3://bucket/vehicles/${agency}/${year}/${month}/${day}/${hour}/',
    
    'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a [View](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html) that includes a timestamp field constructed from the year/moth/day/hour fields (see [How to combine day, month, year fields into a date in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720553/174777)). You can then use standard date/timestamp comparisons on the field. Alternatively, you could convert it into a text field (typically `yyyy-mm-dd hh:min`) -- this allows easy comparisons, but does not support math (eg adding 7 days).

Comment: this is a great idea I needed to do this anyway, but format doesn't seem to be a supported function on athena

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use this partition projection configuration:

```
…
PARTITIONED BY (
  agency string,
  date string,
  hour string
)
…
TBLPROPERTIES (
  …
  'projection.enabled' = 'true',
  'projection.agency.type' = 'injected',
  'projection.date.type' = 'date',
  'projection.date.interval' = '1',
  'projection.date.format' = 'yyyy/MM/dd',
  'projection.date.unit' = 'DAYS',
  'projection.hour.type' = 'integer',
  'projection.hour.range' = '0-23',
  'projection.hour.digits' = '2',
  'storage.location.template' = 's3://bucket/vehicles/${agency}/${date}/${hour}/'
)
```

This will make it possible to query your table like this:

```
WHERE "date" = '2022/08/31'
   OR "date" = '2022/09/01'
```

Just note that if you call the partition key "date" you need to quote it since it's a keyword, you can call it "day" or "dt" if you don't want to quote it. Also note that the partition key won't be of type `DATE`, it will be of type `STRING`. It's also a good idea to set a range for the date column, e.g. `'partition.date.range' = '2022/01/01,NOW'`

The trick here is that even though it may look like the partition keys and directory structure needs to have a 1:1 mapping, that's not how things actually work. At the end of the day all that happens is that partition key values are inserted into the storage location template. Slashes aren't treated any differently than anything else. The location of a partition isn't tied to the values of the partition keys, it's just a mapping (i.e. the partition `('agency1', '2022/09/03', '03')` is mapped to an S3 URI, but to Athena the S3 URI is opaque).

Comment: I have for sure tried this before and was seeing some performance issues with it, but I think that the thing that I ended up leaving out was the query data type needing to be string rather than date.

I believe that I had formatted the date as date('yyyy/MM/dd') in the athena query the passed, but returned no results.