# Aggregate columns in Athena

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have these 3 columns:

| Year | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022 | 6 | 13 |

And I want to create one column for date

| Date |
| --- |
| 2023-5-1 |
| 2022-6-13 |

I'm doing this in Athena.

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT
    year,
    month,
    day,
    array_join(array_agg('year','month','day'), '-') AS aggregated_dates , 
    count(*) AS aggregated_dates
FROM "my_table"
```

This was error:

> Unexpected parameters (varchar(4), varchar(5), varchar(3)) for
> function array_agg. Expected: array_agg(T) T

I also tried

```
SELECT *, 
  translate(format('%t', array_agg(struct(year,month,day))),'()', '') AS dates
FROM "my_table"
```

But I got error that functions struct, format are not registered.

Do you have a better idea how to create that one column?

Comment: What is the format of the columns? Are they text (most probably, due to the Day column having a leading zero in `01`), or numbers? It would possibly be better to convert the elements into an actual `Date`, which can then be formatting how you wish.

Comment: Sorry, I correct the form of the table now. They are all just numbers.

Comment: Since you have changed your Question to make all fields numbers, you could convert them to a true Date object using [How to combine day, month, year fields into a date in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61089240/174777) and then either use default ISO formatting (2023-05-01) or use `date_format()` to convert it to the desired format. See: [Date and Time Functions and Operators — Presto 0.279 Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_agg` is [aggregation function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) which can be used over single column either with `group_by` or in [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html). Since you want to concat several columns in single row you can use either concatenation approach (based on the comment to the other answer since your data type is int you need to cast to varchar):

```sql
select  cast(year as varchar) || '-' || cast(month as varchar) || '-' || cast(day  as varchar) aggregated_dates;
from ...
```

or modify your `array_join` approach by just creating the array from 3 columns:

```sql
select array_join(array[year, month, day], '-') aggregated_dates;
from ...
```

P.S.

Note that `'year'` is not a column, it is just a string containing word "year".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `concat` in AWS

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT year || '-' || month || '-' || day as Date FROM mytable;
```

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', day) as date FROM mytable;
```

Reference:[Concatenating Strings in AWS Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/concatenating-strings-and-arrays.html)

Comment: I tried that also, but I got new error:

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (integer, integer, integer) for function concat. Expected: concat(char(x), char(y)) , concat(array(E), E) E, concat(E, array(E)) E, concat(array(E)) E, concat(varchar) , concat(varbinary)